# Effect of disabling dedicated graphics card in laptop

Tags: laptop, gpu, dell-xps

I just bought the Dell XPS 15 9500, the battery was lasting 3 hours. I think its because VS Code’s node task is very power hungry.

In order to lower the laptops battery discharge rate, I turned of disabled the GTX 1650 TI, which was drawing 2-6 watts even at 0% usage.

I was wondering what day-to-day tasks will be affected by doing this? For example web surfing, Excel, CAD.

Comment: If it works with the on-board graphics and gives your better battery life, there is probably no harm in working this way.

Comment: @John Thanks! But what applications aside from gaming can take advantage of the GPU?

Comment: I cannot tell from the above. You would need to test the applications to see. Most office applications should run fine on a regular GPU.

Comment: You’re asking a generally too broad question that really comes down to your comfort level. So if there is a desire for you to understand what might be affected the absolute best answer anyone can give is simply: Just do whatever you do and if you notice things being sluggish disabling the graphics card might be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAD will definitely be affected, as would any graphic design type software. To what extent I can't say, it depends entirely on the power of your onboard GPU and the complexity of your CAD project. For example, if you're modeling something simple the onboard GPU may handle it just fine, but as your design grows in complexity the program will become sluggish. If you're running Windows 10, which has a graphics heavy UI, it may become sluggish much faster than with an older OS. I don't run Windows 10, so can't say first hand. Movies (whether they be HD YouTube or BlueRay) also run off the GPU. Technically speaking, everything you physically see on a computer runs off the graphics card these days.

Bottom line, everything will initially work off the onboard graphics, but as you (the user) push those GPU intensive applications (CAD, Gaming, movies, etc.) the GPU will reach its limits. When that happens, you'll know you need to reactivate the dedicated GPU.